# Changing Micro Chart – Harvey Ball size in the sap.m.CustomTile dynamically

Tags: css, sapui5

I customized the [sap.m.CustomTile](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.CustomTile.html) with [sap.suite.ui.microchart.HarveyBallMicroChart](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.microchart.HarveyBallMicroChart.html). I need this CustomTile to be resizable according to display resolution e.g. from 319 px to 1920 px. I used for this:

```
.tileSmall.sapMCustomTile {
    width: 29vw !important; 
    height: 29vw !important; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #e5e7e8;        
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

    .tileSmall.sapMCustomTile {
        width: 41vw !important;
        height: 41vw !important;
        margin: 4vw 0vw 0vw 4vw !important;
/*      top, right, bottom, left - margin help */
    }

    .tileHarveyChart {
        height: 10vw !important;
        margin-left: 0.5vw !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {

    .tileSmall.sapMCustomTile {     
        width: 84vw !important;
        height: 84vw !important;
        margin: 6vw 0vw 0vw 6vw !important;
    }

    .tileHarveyChart {
        height: 20vw !important;
        margin-left: 2vw !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 319px) {

    .tileSmall.sapMCustomTile {     
        width: 270px !important;
        height: 270px !important;
        margin: 6vw 0vw 0vw 6vw !important;
    }

    .tileHarveyChart {
        height: 10vw !important;
        margin-left: 0.5vw !important;
    }
}
```

I would like to get something like that (resolution 1305px):

[image]

The chart should be in the middle (vertically), but when I move to smaller resolution e.g. 385px, the tile is overflowing:

[image]

Is there any way how to change the size of HarveyBallMicroChart dynamically according to resolution? Do you have any idea why it is overflowing?

Thanks for any hint.

Here is [demo](http://jsbin.com/dobequsale/1/edit?html,css,output).

EDITED 250817 14:15 => Added element inspection, because of conversation in the comments bellow answer:

[image]

Comment: Try using `vh` for height rather than `vw`, also in your demo, i cant actually reproduce what you are seeing using chrome dev tools.

Comment: Thanks Deckerz, it is same result with "vh". Did you try to change resolution of "Output" window? I am using also Chrome (Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)). IMHO demo should work in any browser (e.g. I tried also IE11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some faffing around i got it to work i believe. See [demo](http://jsbin.com/diwizizufi/edit?html,css,output).

Turns out you needed to override hard coded width and height variables.

I did this like so...

```
.sapSuiteHBMC.sapSuiteHBMCResponsive{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .sapSuiteHBMC.sapSuiteHBMCResponsive svg{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Deckerz, I upvoted you answer, it did what I needed. I wait until friday for other solutions. How did you know svg must be used?

Comment: because when you inspect element it all, these two selects divs/svgs where receiving inline styling via the plugin. So you just needed to override them.

Comment: Can you please explain me, how did you find out that class sapSuiteHBMC must be connected with class sapSuiteHBMCResponsive as .sapSuiteHBMC.sapSuiteHBMCResponsive? I added picture of element inspection and these classes are not connected..

Comment: Two classes combined in a CSS select means target something that has both classes i.e. .class1.class2 would target something with class1 AND class2 on it.

Comment: And how did you know these two are connected? Or try-catch approach?

Comment: @Jaro you know they are connected because in your screenshot it shows both class names inline on the SVG

Comment: I understand they are connected now, but how did you know that class sapSuiteHBMCResponsive is under class sapSuiteHBMC, before you connected them.

Comment: I will be glad to give you bounty, if you will help me to understand this.

Comment: they are not under per say they are next to. Ill give you an example, `<div class="me you"><div class="otherguy"></div></div>`. In this example to target the inner div you would do `.me .otherguy` but to target the outer div you could use either `.me` or `.me.you` the latter is just a stronger version of targeting to ensure that the CSS will not be over written

Comment: Here is a website which may explain it better: https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/ See double class selector section